# Left Outer join not returning expected resultSet

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, join, sql-server-2012

I have these two tables

```
              #TABLE1#
##CompanyName##    ##PrimaryKey##
DELL                     1
DELL CALIFORNIA          2
DELL SAN FRANCISCO       3
DELL LOS ANGELES         4
IBM                      5
GOOGLE                   6

                                     #TABLE2#
##ParentComp##   ##ParentPrimaryKey##       ##ChildComp##    ##ChildPrimaryKey##
    DELL                     1             DELL CALIFORNIA            2
DELL CALIFORNIA              2             DELL SAN FRANCISCO         3
DELL CALIFORNIA              2             DELL LOS ANGELES           4
```

Now the expected table is shown as below; the relationship(hierarchy) column has only three possible values(PARENT/CHILD/INDEPENDENT) as shown:

```
                               #TABLE3#
##CompanyName##             ##Relationship##                     ##ParentCompany##
DELL                             PARENT                                ---
DELL CALIFORNIA                  CHILD                                 DELL
DELL SAN FRANCISCO               CHILD                             DELL CALIFORNIA
DELL LOS ANGELES                 CHILD                             DELL CALIFORNIA
IBM                           INDEPENDENT                              ---
GOOGLE                        INDEPENDENT                              ---
```

I have already tried the following two join options

> Select 
>   ...
>   Table1
>  
>   Left Outer Join
>   Table2 ON Table1.PrimaryKey = Table2.ParentPrimaryKey
>   Left Outer Join
>   Table2 tAlias2 
>   Table2.ParentPrimaryKey = tAlias2.ChildPrimaryKey

returns

```
 ##CompanyName##               ##Relationship##                     ##ParentCompany##
    DELL                             PARENT                                ---
    DELL CALIFORNIA                  CHILD                                 DELL
    DELL SAN FRANCISCO            INDEPENDENT                              ---
    DELL LOS ANGELES              INDEPENDENT                              ---
    IBM                           INDEPENDENT                              ---
    GOOGLE                        INDEPENDENT                              ---
```

or

> Select 
>   ...
>   Table1
>  
>   Left Outer Join
>   Table2 ON Table1.PrimaryKey = Table2.ChildPrimaryKey
>   Left Outer Join
>   Table1 tAlias1 
>   Table2.ParentPrimaryKey = tAlias1.PrimaryKey

will return something like this:

```
 ##CompanyName##               ##Relationship##                     ##ParentCompany##
    DELL                           INDEPENDENT                             ---
    DELL CALIFORNIA                  CHILD                                 DELL
    DELL SAN FRANCISCO               CHILD                              DELL CALIFORNIA
    DELL LOS ANGELES                 CHILD                              DELL CALIFORNIA
    IBM                            INDEPENDENT                             ---
    GOOGLE                         INDEPENDENT                             ---
```

Comment: Mysql and ms sql are 2 different products. Pls remove the irrelevant tag.

Comment: Perhaps something like `SELECT T.companyName, MAX(COALESCE(T2.relationship, T2A.relationship, 'INDEPENDENT')) relationship, MAX(T2.parentCompany) parentCompany FROM table1 T LEFT JOIN (SELECT 'CHILD', T2.childPrimaryKey, T1.companyName FROM table2 T2 JOIN table1 T1 ON T1.primaryKey = T2.parentPrimaryKey) T2(relationship, childPrimaryKey, parentCompany) ON T2.childPrimaryKey = T.primaryKey LEFT JOIN (SELECT 'PARENT', parentPrimaryKey FROM table2) T2A(relationship, parentPrimaryKey) ON T2A.parentPrimaryKey = T.primaryKey GROUP BY T.companyName;`

Answer (score 0):

When you join `talias2.ChildPrimaryKey` you need to join with `Table1.PrimaryKey` column.

```
SELECT ..
FROM   table1 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 
                    ON table1.primarykey = table2.parentprimarykey 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 talias2 
                    ON table1.primarykey = talias2.childprimarykey --here
```

When you join `tAlias2.ChildPrimaryKey` with `table2.parentprimarykey` then only the matched records from `table2` and `table1`(`table1.primarykey = table2.parentprimarykey`) will be joined with `tAlias2.ChildPrimaryKey`

Answer (score 0):

Your schema is obviously redundant. You can drop `table2` and receive all you want from following.

```
declare @tbl table (CompanyName varchar(100),PrimaryKey int primary key, parentId int)

insert @tbl values
('DELL',                     1,null),
('DELL CALIFORNIA',          2,1),
('DELL SAN FRANCISCO',       3,2),
('DELL LOS ANGELES',         4,2),
('IBM',                      5,null),
('google',                   6,null)


;with tbl as (
select PrimaryKey, CompanyName, parentId,
rel = cast(case when exists(select 1 from @tbl t1 where t1.parentId=t.PrimaryKey) then 'parent'
      else 'independent' end as varchar(100)),
cast(null as varchar(100)) parentName
from @tbl t
where t.parentId is null
union all
select t.PrimaryKey, t.CompanyName, t.parentId,cast('child' as varchar(100)),
tbl.CompanyName
from @tbl t inner join tbl on t.parentId=tbl.PrimaryKey
)
select * from tbl

order by PrimaryKey
```